# Parsing ASPX page in C#

Tags: parsing

How can I parse an ASPX page such as this : http://www.shufersal.co.il/Pages/Catalog.aspx# to strings in C#? this website is shopping site and I want to take some details from it such as a product name and a price? Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTML Agility Pack for this. More information can be found here:

http://www.google.nl/url?sa=f&rct=j&url=http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx&q=html+agility+pack+tutorial&ei=hwodUKGlHu220QWJmYBo&usg=AFQjCNH4auAyTI9GTpM2cistPrGGnMHLeg

There are also some examples available. It's very easy to use if your familliar with linq to X queries.

Comment: yes it does, it's just a DLL you can include inside your project.